# expect script not sending password correctly

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, tcl

This is the end goal: execute a mysql command using the expect script to send password when prompted. There are 3 files in total

1. test.sh
2. test1.sh
3. test.exp

Here are the codes:

> test.sh  (returns the password that is needed to connect to mysql database)

```
grep hibernate.connection.password /opt/cisco/cpam/properties/vx.hibernate.properties | sed 's/hibernate.connection.password=//g'
```

> test1.sh  (the mysql command that needs to be excecuted)

```
mysql -u cpam -p --protocol=tcp vxdb < /opt/cisco/cpam/import/MySQL_Views.sql
```

> test.exp (the expect script that sends password while executing mysql command)

```
set password [exec ./test.sh]
exec ./test1.sh
expect "Enter password: "
send  "$password\r"
expect eof
```

The result of me running expect test.exp is that I only see the prompt:

```
Enter password:
```

Any expert can lend me a hand to see what is going wrong? It certain means that test1.sh has run successfully, and also I have tried many times, including using just static password. Still just the prompt.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a program to be interactable-with via `expect` and `send`, you need to launch it with `spawn` and not `exec`. Try this:

```
set password [exec ./test.sh]
spawn ./test1.sh
expect "Enter password: "
send  "$password\r"
expect eof
```